# ssh on a vm - Address family not supported by protocol family

Tags: ssh, sshd

I'm trying to SSH into a Debian Buster Virtualbox host on my macOS laptop (Mojave), but keep getting the error `Address family not supported by protocol family`. Not sure how this could be an IPv6 issue since I've disabled IPv6 in the /etc/hosts of the vm and my laptop.

Here's the `/etc/hosts` of my laptop:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
```

Here's the `/etc/hosts` of the vm:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       debian
```

Here's the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of the vm:

```
Port 22
AddressFamily any
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
UseDNS no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Here's my local vm's iptables config:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

My username is the same on my laptop as on the vm. I got the IP address based on `arp -a` output. Here's the command I'm running and the output I get.

```
└─[$] <> ssh 224.0.0.251
ssh: connect to host 224.0.0.251 port 22: Address family not supported by protocol family
```

Comment: `224.0.0.251` is a multicast address—you cannot ssh to this.

Comment: @Torin welp that'd be my problem then. I selected the wrong IP. Thanks!

Comment: More generally, as well as not using multicast addresses for individual hosts, never use an IP address that doesn't belong to you.  Use the [RFC-1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) private networks: 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, or 10.0.0.0/8.   These are reserved for anyone to use within private networks and will never be allocated to anyone or routed on the internet.